# How do I draw a shape and then play a sound using Python Qt4?

Tags: python, qt4

Using Python QT4, I would like to draw a line on a widget and then starting playing a sound. I don't understand why it happens vice versa, i.e when I run the program I first hear the sound and then a line is drawn.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import gtk
import pygame


class DrawLine(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        # setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Draw a line and then play a song')

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        paint = QPainter()
        paint.begin(self)
        paint.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        paint.setBrush(Qt.white)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2, Qt.SolidLine)
        paint.setPen(pen) 
        paint.drawLine(20, 80, 250, 80)
        paint.end()
        play()

    global play  
    def play():
        file_name = "/home/train_ipa/ipa_b.wav"
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file_name)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
            continue

app = QApplication([])
line = DrawLine()
line.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It MIGHT be because the class is starting all functions at once. After all there's no call to "paintEvent", it could entirely just be running it straight away. There's two options here.. 1) move the sound code into the paintEven function. 2) move the def play() back in indentation so it's not part of the class. that way when it gets called it'll only run it then.

Comment: Hi Keef. Thanks for your answer. The first option doesn't make any difference. I haven't tried the second option yet, however I've solved the problem by delaying the play with QTimer.singleShot. I feel like this has to do with how Qt Event Loop operates and I have lack of understanding that.